# NullReferenceException on Back Navigation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am working on a Windows Phone 8+ App.
I have a Page with the details of an Item. Each Item can be a component of another Item, and so I have two ListBoxes containing the other Items that can be composed or compose the current Item.

```
        JItem.Item currItem;
        List<JItem.Item> components;
        List<JItem.Item> isComponentOf;
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {

            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            currItemId = NavigationContext.QueryString["item_id"];

            currItem = (JItem.Item)App.itemsDict[currItemId];
            LayoutRoot.DataContext = currItem;

            components = new List<JItem.Item>();
            isComponentOf = new List<JItem.Item>();
            foreach (var x in currItem.components)
            {
                components.Add((JItem.Item)App.itemsDict[x]);
            }
            foreach (var x in currItem.composes)
            {
                isComponentOf.Add((JItem.Item)App.itemsDict[x]);
            }
            componentsLB.ItemsSource = components;
            composesLB.ItemsSource = isComponentOf;
            if (components.Count == 0) 
                componentsLabel.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
            if (isComponentOf.Count == 0) 
                isComponentLabel.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
```

If I navigate forward selecting an Item in the `componentsLB` ListBox or in the `isComponentOf`ListBox it all works fine. If I go back to a page through the Back button, I get a `System.NullReferenceException` on the `componentsLB.ItemsSource = components;` line, even if the `components` contains items and the `componentsLB` is allocated.

Since it's on the NavigationStack, the page is not re-initialized, (`InitializeComponent()` in the constructor is not called) but the ListBox are allocated.

I could use some workarounds (not reloading the data as example) when the page is accessed through a Back navigation, but I'd like to understand what is causing the error.

This is the Stacktrace of the exception that bubbles up:

```
   at DOTA2_Pocket.ItemDetails.componentsLB_SelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.InvokeSelectionChanged(List`1 unselectedItems, List`1 selectedItems)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.OnItemCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.NotifyCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.UpdateItemsSourceList(IEnumerable newItemsSource)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.ItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChangeNotifications(DependencyProperty dp, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.set_ItemsSource(IEnumerable value)
   at DOTA2_Pocket.ItemDetails.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.InternalOnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.Microsoft.Phone.Controls.IPhoneApplicationPage.InternalOnNavigatedToX(NavigationEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.RaiseNavigated(Object content, Uri uri, NavigationMode mode, Boolean isNavigationInitiator, IPhoneApplicationPage existingContentPage, IPhoneApplicationPage newContentPage)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.CompleteNavigation(DependencyObject content, NavigationMode mode)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.<>c__DisplayClass7.<NavigateCore_StartNavigation>b__4()
```

Comment: Debugger is your friend. "Debug, Exceptions...", check the "CLR exception", run your app under the debugger, reproduce the problem, and from the call stack you'll find out what exact null have you referenced.

Comment: Let's see a stack trace! Set a breakpoint at the beginning of the function and step through it!

Comment: Of course debugging is the first thing I've attempted, but I can't exactly seem to figure out where is the error.
I added the stacktrace to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information that you have provided it looks like your **App.itemsDict** contains a null reference that you are adding to the **components** List variable. The **SelectedChanged** event of your ListBox is then throwing a **NullReference** exception because it is trying to perform an operation on that null reference.

Comment: Checked it, but there is no null in the dictionary, plus, it would be the same binding that was made the first time (which was done successfully).

Comment: You say that the exception occurs when you assign the components variable to the ItemsSource of the ListBox but yet the stacktrace is saying that it occurs in the SelectedChanged event. Do you have an event handler wired up to that event and if you do have you put a breakpoint there?